# Filter with 'like' on SQLAlchemy association proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using an association proxy in SQLAlchemy to avoid constantly joining in a table (`Entity`) that contains only `name`, as `entity_proper_name`:

```
class Institution(Base):

    entity_id = Column(
        String(8, u'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
        ForeignKey(Entity.entity_id),
        primary_key=True)
    entity = relationship(Entity, uselist=False)
    name = association_proxy('entity', 'entity_proper_name')
```

I can query the class with `==`, but not with `.like`:

```
query = s.query(Institution).filter(Institution.name=='Correct Name')
# works fine

query = s.query(Institution).filter(Institution.name.like('%Correct N%')
# AttributeError: 'AssociationProxy' object has no attribute 'like'
```

Is there way to use `.like`, without rejecting the association proxy approach?

Comment: Not elegant but `query = s.query(Institution).filter(Institution.name.remote_attr.like('%Correct N%')` would work.

Comment: Additionally you can also do `query = s.query(Institution).filter(Institution. entity.has(Entity.entity_proper_name.like('%Correct N%')))` but then you aren't using the association_proxy.

Answer (score 2):

While the question was very old - there was no answer ...  and doesn't seem like a good solution has come up yet.

I just had the same issue and did the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import AssociationProxy

def like_filter(attr, *args, **kwargs):
    filter_attr = attr
    if isinstance(filter_attr, AssociationProxy):  # If assoc_proxy get remote_attr as like() doesnt work
        filter_attr = filter_attr.remote_attr
    return filter_attr.like(*args, **kwargs)
```

So, now I can do:

`s.query(Institution).filter(like_filter(Institution.name, '%Correct N%'))`

Not ideal. Definitely a workaround. But works :)